# What's the difference between bringToFront in Android 4 and Android 5?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-scrollview, bringtofront

I've got this layout with a DrawerLayout and a ScrollView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".InformacionTienda">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/quienesSomosCv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quienesSomosCabecera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="#010001"
                    android:text="¿Quiénes somos?"
                    android:textColor="#fffcf7"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tamano_localizacion" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quienesSomosTexto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/quienesSomosCabecera"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test " />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/mapaCv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/localizacionCabecera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="#010001"
                    android:text="Localización"
                    android:textColor="#fffcf7"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tamano_localizacion" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mapa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tamano_mapa"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/localizacionCabecera"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/empresa_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/contactoCv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactoCabecera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="#010001"
                    android:text="Contacto"
                    android:textColor="#fffcf7"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tamano_localizacion" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/telefono"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/contactoCabecera"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Telefono: 666 666 666" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/botonLlamar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/telefono"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/telefono"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/botonMail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/telefono"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/telefono"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/botonLlamar"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/calle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/telefono"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Calle: El 742 de Evergreen Terrace" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/calle"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="www.facebook.com" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/facebook"
                    android:autoLink="email"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="email@email.com" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<!-- Contenido de la actividad -->
<include layout="@layout/content_layout" />
<!-- Navigation Drawer Layout -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer_layout" />
```

```
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Anyone knows why it's look like this in Android 4? (and works perfectly):
http://snag.gy/DKgk9.jpg

And why looks like in Android 5?
http://snag.gy/WjVXh.jpg

`bringChildToFront` function does the same.

Comment: Are you talking about v21 and v19?

Comment: I tested in real terminals, Android 5.0.1 and Android 4.2.2

Comment: Actually, I have this in the activity:


sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
sv.bringToFront();
If I comment this lines I can use the navDrawer bar, but then I can't scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution!

I only need to put a LinearLayout as father of the scrollView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".InformacionTienda">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/testlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:paddingTop="70dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/quienesSomosCv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quienesSomosCabecera"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="#010001"
                        android:text="¿Quiénes somos?"
                        android:textColor="#fffcf7"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/tamano_localizacion" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quienesSomosTexto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/quienesSomosCabecera"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test " />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/mapaCv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/localizacionCabecera"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="#010001"
                        android:text="Localización"
                        android:textColor="#fffcf7"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/tamano_localizacion" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/mapa"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/tamano_mapa"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/localizacionCabecera"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/empresa_icon" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/contactoCv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/contactoCabecera"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="#010001"
                        android:text="Contacto"
                        android:textColor="#fffcf7"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/tamano_localizacion" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/telefono"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/contactoCabecera"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Telefono: 666 666 666" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/botonLlamar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/telefono"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/telefono"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/botonMail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/telefono"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/telefono"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/botonLlamar"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/calle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/telefono"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Calle: El 742 de Evergreen Terrace" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/facebook"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/calle"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="www.facebook.com" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/facebook"
                        android:autoLink="email"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="email@email.com" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Contenido de la actividad -->
<include layout="@layout/content_layout" />
<!-- Navigation Drawer Layout -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer_layout" />
```

Many thanks!